# How to set a certain width of the page for the grid container?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a layout that has 4 columns in a row with different width, but also should only take around 70-80% of the page. But once I set the width of the parent-container or add margins to the container, the content inside the grid rows starts to overlap other columns, how do I prevent it?

```
<style>

    .instructions-wrapper {
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 5%; /*if I delete this row, it all works as expected. I tried width: 80%, same things happens.*/
    }

    .one {
        background-color: red;
    }

    .two {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    
    .three {
        background-color: blue;
    }

    .four {
        background-color: purple;
    }


</style>

<div class="instructions-wrapper">
    <h1>text</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-1 one">
                2019
            </div> 
            <div class="col-lg-2 two">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100"> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-7 three">
                text
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 four">
                text
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The margin is making the container smaller and it makes the columns too small for the content so it has to overlap.

For example you give column "two" 2 parts of the grid and your image is 100px.

- If your container is 1200px. then 2 parts is 200px including padding which is 30px.
- If the container is 780px wide then 2 parts is 130px - this is the full width of your image and padding
- **so if your container gets smaller than 780px then this grid cell will start overlapping.**

This is your code using `width:80%` and when you look at it in full page it still works. So your container is just getting too small.

```css
.instructions-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  width:80%;
}

.one {
  background-color: red;
}

.two {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.three {
  background-color: blue;
}

.four {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="instructions-wrapper">
  <h1>text</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-1 one">
        2019
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 two">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-7 three">
        text
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 four">
        text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so could help with the possible ways to solve this problem?

Comment: @syntanic The only problem is your content is too big, so make your content smaller or put it in grid cells that are big enough for it. My answer explains what is happening so you can use this information to fix it.

Comment: @syntanic if my answer explained to you the problem and what you must do to fix it, you might accept it or upvote it :) It might not be what you want to know but it is the answer, you cannot fit bigger content into smaller spaces so one has to change :)